# Is it possible to delete contacts in Marketing Cloud that will reduce Distinct Contact Count?

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are trying to reduce our overall Distinct Contact Count in our marketing Cloud org. We can see the Total Population in our business unit (there is just one) it is around 500k, however at Account Level our Distinct Contact Count is over 1m. We have been adding in Mobile SDK pageviews by API and I believe this has been responsible for our increase in contacts however we cannot see the actual contacts that have been created....any help would be appreciated greatly, as Salesforce have been little help.

Comment: Do you have a list of ContactKeys or ContactIDs that you want to delete ?